# Onceler gives wrong tokens (bitskins api)

Tags: node.js

i have a problem with node.js' onceler package. I want to get access to the public bitskins API. I have 2 servers. A free webspace (cloud9-ide) and one virtual server. This is my code:

```
var TOTP = require('onceler').TOTP;
var totp = new TOTP('SECRET_CODE');
console.log(totp.at());
```

I run this on my free cloud9 webspace and I get my correct token, which i can use to get access to the public API of bitskins.

Now i run the **exactly** same code on my server, and i get *only* wrong tokens, all the time. Both server's uses the same onceler package (0.0.5), but they give me different tokens. What could be the reason(s)?

I tried to update the package, or to import the package of my cloud9-server. But nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use totp.now() instead of totp.at().   totp.at takes a parameter for the time in which you want to generate the otp.

Another way to tackle this is to use speakeasy:

```
var speakeasy = require("speakeasy");
var token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: config.get("bitSkins").otpCode,
  encoding: 'base32'
});
console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to synchronize your device's clock.

## Ubuntu Example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntp -y
```